# Can't return response from httpclient post function to other custom function in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient, angular4-httpclient

I have `addUser(newUser)` function in sign-in.service.ts file as follows

```
addUser(newUser)
  {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    let body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
    this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', body, httpOptions).subscribe(res=>{
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    });
  }
```

Here console's output is `{msg: "succesfully added", status: 200}`
but when i m calling the above `addUser(newUser)` function from sign-in.component.ts file as follows

```
  addUser()
  {
    console.log(this.first_name,this.last_name,this.userName,this.email);
    let newUser = {
      "first_name":this.first_name,
      "last_name":this.last_name,
      "username":this.userName,
      "email":this.email
    }
    console.log(this.signService.addUser(newUser));
  }
```

console output is showing `undefined` . Why? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: hi, can you please try out solution given and let me know if you face any issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpclient is going to return you observable as per my knowledge and it logs response in subscribe method so in component you might not receive things properly as call is not completed , so you need to do like this

```
addUser(newUser) : Observable<any>
  {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    let body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
    return this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', body, httpOptions);
  }

 //make use of async/awit , so you will get response properly 
 async addUser()
  {
    console.log(this.first_name,this.last_name,this.userName,this.email);
    let newUser = {
      "first_name":this.first_name,
      "last_name":this.last_name,
      "username":this.userName,
      "email":this.email
    }
    const datareturned = await this.signService.addUser(newUser).toPromise();
    console.log(datareturned);
  }
```

or if you dont want to go for async/await , you should surbscribe observable in your component.ts file

```
addUser()
  {
    console.log(this.first_name,this.last_name,this.userName,this.email);
    let newUser = {
      "first_name":this.first_name,
      "last_name":this.last_name,
      "username":this.userName,
      "email":this.email
    }
   this.signService.addUser(newUser).subscribe(d=> console.log(d));
  }
```

service file

```
addUser(newUser) : Observable<any>
  {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };
    let body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
    return this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', body, httpOptions);
  }
```

Comment: First addUser(newUser) function give error:A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: you missed return statement before `this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', body, httpOptions);`

Comment: @SureshKumarDhayal - welcome , you can upvote too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

The component code does not wait for the service call to finish.

```
// sign-in.service.ts
addUser(newUser) {
    const httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
    };
    let body = JSON.stringify(newUser);
    return this.httpclient.post('http://localhost:3000/api/signup', body, httpOptions)
}

// Component
addUser() {
    console.log(this.first_name, this.last_name, this.userName, this.email);
    let newUser = {
        "first_name": this.first_name,
        "last_name": this.last_name,
        "username": this.userName,
        "email": this.email
    }
    this.signService.addUser(newUser).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because...

`console.log` is not `async` but your `http` service is, so when `console.log` is executed your service is still waiting for the `response` that's why it's `undefined`.

To make it work you have to use `promise` or `observable`.